# Fix time string formats and convert to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, time

I got a list of Time attributes. Need to convert them into timestamps but there are lots of wrong-formatted ones. is there a way to quickly convert them into readable strings like having double quotes among hours and minutes?

Example:
190     c: 1:00 
213     c:17:00 
228     c: 2:00 
279     c:09:00 
1462     c16:50 
2599    c:09:00 
3390     c14:30 
4838    c: 9:40 
1710    12'20 
2222    1114:20

I've succeeded on the 'c:' ones but didn't find a solution for the other wrong formatted ones.

```
df.loc[df['Time'].str.startswith('c:') == True,'Time'] = df.loc[df['Time'].str.startswith('c:') == True,'Time'].str.split("c:").str[1]
```

Comment: You should specify what the output should be.  If I understand, the output of `190 c: 1:00` would be `190 c: "1:00"`?

Comment: exactly, @SciProg but there are different observations like 12'20 or 18.10 I wanted to ask if there is a way to specify all those as time strings and convert them to TimeDelta's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small program that should help you.

```
import re

REGEX = re.compile(r"(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)")

TESTS = (
  "3390 c14:30", 
  "4838 c: 9:40",
  "1710 12'20",
  "2222 1114:20",
)

for test in TESTS:
  match = REGEX.match(test)
  if match:
    number = int(match.group(1))
    hour = int(match.group(2))
    second = int(match.group(3))
    print('%d "%d:%d"' % (number, hour, second))
  else:
    print(test)
```

Here is the output.

```
3390 "14:30"
4838 "9:40"
1710 "12:20"
2222 "1114:20"
```

It uses regular expressions.  In short, the regular expression searches for three groups of consecutive digits `(\d+)`.  Each group is separated by any number of non digits `[^\d]+`.

The parentheses allow extracting the digits.

You can consult python documentation about regular expressions.